# Query for regain deleted account of Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, user-accounts

I have Win 8 Pro, Built 9200. Accidentally the activated account has been deleted. Now the problem is, it asks me for password while starting my laptop. Is there any way to regain my deleted account? Or, Do you have any trick to run my laptop without entering password? Please me to overcome this problem.

Comment: I would log into the default `Administrator` account and create a user profile you can log into.  Without a System Restore point its not possible to undelete an Windows account.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that has saved me many a time is booting into the Windows recovery mode and hoping you have a recent System Restore Point.

If you happen to have one this should be able to roll you back to before you deleted your User account and save you a whole lot of trouble.

Hope this helps :)